# How to add “chapters” or “bookmarks” to movies?

Tags: macos, video, video-editing, mp4, chapters

## Is there an easy way to add chapters to existing movie files?

**Note:**

- Actually, I’m not 100% sure if they’re called “chapters” in video files, but it’s the same concept as DVDs.
- I assume this differs with the video encoding, but any help at all is progress!  I have video files in various formats (although .mov, .mp4, and .m4v are my most common).
- I’m on Mac OS X, but I posted here (instead of the Apple Q&A) because I figured any answers may be useful to other non-Apple power users.
- Apple-native, application-based solutions preferred (usability is top of my list).  However, command-line programs and utilities that do the job are just as welcome.
- Please share any indirect-but-related wisdom you may have on this topic.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they're called chapters. QuickTime Player X uses that term in the menu and controller.

Comment: [`ffmpeg`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) can add/edit chapters in an existing video, without re-encoding the video or audio streams. It's not user-friendly, but it's free and extremely powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Are these movies you created yourself? Or did you obtain them from "other" sources?

If they are movies you created yourself you can use iMovie or QuickTime.

If not, I recommend using [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) for transcoding into a single video format then using [MetaX](http://www.kerstetter.net/index.php/projects/software/metax) to add metadata (including chapters).

Comment: These aren't movies I created.  Downloaded Handbrake and MetaX, gonna try them out.  Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: I tried MetaX, and it’s pretty good at lots of things, but it doesn’t seem to add Chapters to movie files unless they have at least 1 Chapter already.  That probably won’t be helpful for this problem too often, because most movies that have Chapters tend to be sufficient to skip around.  I want to be able to add my own Chapters so that I can navigate movies more efficiently than just scrubbing.